# Integrating $\int_0^1 x^xdx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

How would you calculate the following integral?
$$\int_0^1 x^xdx$$

I write my answer below. Don't be shy to speak out if you find the mistakes (if there are any) or have a better solution.

Comment: That is well-known: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream

Comment: Congratulations on re-discovering this.  (Do not let the fact that it was already known discourage you.) Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to notice that
$$x^x=e^{\ln x^x}=e^{x\ln x}$$
Only to calculate
$$\int_0^1 e^{x\ln x}dx$$
According to Taylor-expansion, we have
$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
$$\Rightarrow e^{x\ln x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n(\ln x)^n}{n!}$$
$$\Rightarrow \int_0^1 e^{x\ln x}dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^1 x^n(\ln x)^n dx$$
Let $I_n=\int_0^\infty x^n(\ln x)^n dx$, integrate $I_n$ by part
$$I_n=\bigg[\frac{x^{n+1}(\ln x)^n}{n+1}\bigg]_0^1-\frac n{n+1}\int_0^1(\ln x)^{n-1}x^ndx=-\frac n{n+1}\int_0^1(\ln x)^{n-1}x^ndx$$
Repeat this process for another $n-1$ times, we will get
$$I_n=(-1)^n\frac {n!}{(n+1)^n}\int_0^1x^ndx=(-1)^n\frac {n!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$$
$$\Rightarrow \int_0^1 e^{x\ln x}dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}I_n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac {(-1)^{n}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$$
$$\Rightarrow \int_0^1 x^xdx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac {(-1)^{n}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$$

Comment: That converges fast enough to be calculatable and gives the correct value of about $0.78343051$.